# Array cannot be bridged from Objective-C error

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, anyobject

After instantiating an array as an AnyObject type and adding string objects to the array the following code compiles however crashes when attempting to display this array in a textfield.  The program still crashes when attempting to print it out to the debug console as well with the following error message: "fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C".  Is the following method not compatible with swift?

print((jumperCablesRoles as! [String]).joinWithSeparator(","))

Here is the entire code base:

```
    import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Jeffrey Wells", employeeRoles: ["Accountant", "Designer"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Victor Atkins", employeeRoles: ["Director of IT", "Sales Stategist"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Kelli Hamilton", employeeRoles: ["Director of Sales"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Adam Braun", employeeRoles: ["Sales Lead"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Brian Cruz", employeeRoles: ["Designer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Kristen Floyd", employeeRoles: ["Developer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Lois Martinez", employeeRoles: ["Curator", "Blogger"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Michael Lind", employeeRoles: ["Sales, Administrator"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Eric Bay", employeeRoles: ["Database Admin"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Brandon Young", employeeRoles: ["Artist"], departmentID: 2)
    ]
    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Victor Atkins", employeeRoles: ["Director of IT", "Sales Stategist"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Adam Braun", employeeRoles: ["Sales Lead"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Brian Cruz", employeeRoles: ["Designer"], departmentID: 1),
        Employees(name: "Kristen Floyd", employeeRoles: ["Developer"], departmentID: 1)
    ]
    var rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees = [
        Employees(name: "Kelli Hamilton", employeeRoles: ["Director of Sales"], departmentID: 0),
        Employees(name: "Lois Martinez", employeeRoles: ["Curator", "Blogger"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Michael Lind", employeeRoles: ["Sales, Administrator"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Eric Bay", employeeRoles: ["Database Admin"], departmentID: 2),
        Employees(name: "Brandon Young", employeeRoles: ["Artist"], departmentID: 2)
    ]
    var jumperCables: [String] = []
    var jumperCablez: [String] = []
    var jumperCablic: [String] = []
    var jumperCablesRoles: [AnyObject] = []
    var jumperCablezRoles: [String] = []
    var jumperCablicRoles: [String] = []


    @IBOutlet weak var employeePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var employeeNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var employeeListing: UITextView!
    @IBAction func addEmployee(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            var jumperCables: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)

                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[0]
                employeePicker.reloadAllComponents()

        case 1 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1:
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                var jumperCablez: [String] = []
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCablez.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name)
                    chosenManagerScrollView.text = rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name
                }
                employeePicker.reloadAllComponents()

        case 2 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2:
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            var jumperCablig: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCablig.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees[i].name)
            }
            chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCablig[0]
            employeePicker.reloadAllComponents()

        default:
            break; 
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        employeePicker.dataSource = self
        employeePicker.delegate = self

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            return rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count

        case 1 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1:
            return rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count

        case 2 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2:
            return rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees.count

        default:
            return 5
        }

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            var jumperCabled: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCabled.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
            }
            return jumperCabled[row]

        case 1 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1:
            var jumperCabling: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCabling.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name)
            }
            return jumperCabling[row]

        case 2 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2:
            var jumperCab: [String] = []
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCab.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees[i].name)
            }
            return jumperCab[row]

        default:
            return "datsource corrupted"
        }
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) ->UIView {

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
                let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
                    jumperCablesRoles.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].employeeRoles)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView

        case 1 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1:
                let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
                chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees.count ; ++i {
                    jumperCablez.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesVictorsEmployees[i].name)
                }
                chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCablez[row]
                return chosenManagerScrollView

        case 2 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2:
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCablic.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesKellisEmployees[i].name)
            }
            chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCablic[row]
            return chosenManagerScrollView

        default:
            let chosenManagerScrollView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(40,0,170,72))
            chosenManagerScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            for var i = 0; i < rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees.count ; ++i {
                jumperCables.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].name)
            }
            chosenManagerScrollView.text = jumperCables[row]
            return chosenManagerScrollView

        }
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            employeeNameLabel.text = jumperCables[row]
            //employeeListing.text = (jumperCablesRoles as! [String]).joinWithSeparator(",")
            print((jumperCablesRoles as! [String]).joinWithSeparator(","))

        case 1 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1:
            employeeNameLabel.text = jumperCablez[row]

        case 2 where segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2:
            employeeNameLabel.text = jumperCablic[row]

        default:
            employeeNameLabel.text = jumperCables[row]

        }
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you could filter out the irrelevant code, and where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Sure, this was the first line of code I've added to the question.  Maybe you can't see it because it isn't inside the gray notepad.  Here is the line that causes the error again: print((jumperCablesRoles as! [String]).joinWithSeparator(","))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is in this line of code: `jumperCablesRoles.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].employeeRoles)`.

As far as I can tell, `employeeRoles` is an array of `String`s in itself (`[String]`). This means that if you add an employee's `employeeRoles` to the `jumperCablesRoles` array, `jumperCablesRoles` is actually an array which contains an array of `String`s. (`[[String]]`). This is why, when you try to force cast it into `[String]` it will fail.

I'm not sure exactly what you want the result to be, so I can't help you with that, but you can try to append each element of `employeeRoles` separately to `jumperCablesRoles` if that's what you're going for. If that's what you want, just leave a comment and I'll provide additional code.

**Edit**: I just went ahead and found a solution anyways, simply replace `jumperCablesRoles.append(rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].employeeRoles)` with the following:

```
rejuvenatedEnterprisesEmployees[i].employeeRoles.forEach {jumperCablesRoles.append($0)}
```

This adds every `employeeRole` (which is a `String`) to `jumperCablesRoles` separately.

Comment: Much appreciated @kabiroberai as this helped in going the right direction definitely.  As your code helped see the problem through I was able to come up with the following line of code however I don't know exactly why it works: employeeListing.text = (jumperCablesRoles[row] as! [String] as [String]).joinWithSeparator("...")

Comment: @LaurenceWingo I'm glad it worked. Have you tried to remove the second `as [String]` in your solution? It may work too.

Comment: YEEESS!! That's exactly what I did but I'm not sure exactly why this works.  Isn't "as! [String] as [String]" the same type??  It works for my problem but mentally I'm not sure why this works, can you explain?

Comment: @LaurenceWingo I meant to ask whether removing the second one works, by which I meant, what happens when it's just `as! [String]`? I'm as confused as you are in that sense -_-

Comment: @LaurenceWingo could you tell me the error you get when you try `(jumperCablesRoles[row] as! [String]).joinWithSeperator("...")`?

Comment: employeeListing.text = (jumperCablesRoles[row] as! [String]).joinWithSeperator("...") won't compile and gives the following error: "Value of type '[String]' has no member 'joinWithSeperator'"

Comment: @LaurenceWingo strange... I've tried to reproduce it, but haven't had any success doing so yet (`as! [String]` works fine for me). I'll tell you if I figure it out.